# XtraGrid + LINQ2SQL, handling database errors

Tags: gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using XtraGrid with LINQ2SQL as a datasource and I'm having some problems.

Sometimes data validation errors occur while posting changes in database (say in case of unique index violation or trigger error or FK doent exist or you try to delete someone's parent etc). In this case, I need to notify user and make him able to correct data or revert row.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find the best place to put code and make it possible. 
Inside `GridView.ValidateRow` event body no underlying data has been changed yet (and no changes will be caused by `dataContext.SubmitChanges()` call).

The `GridView.RowUpdated` event looks like a good place for saving changes to DB, but i'm unable to keep the error row focused (if user caused row update by moving focus to another row then the focus will go away after this event handler completion).

What is the common solution to handle database errors while insert/update/delete operations in GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Handle the View RowUpdated event;
- Wrap the SubmitChanges call within the try/catch block;
- If any exception is thrown, update the View state accordingly.

Use the following pseudo-code:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;

void SomeViewHere_RowUpdated(object sender, RowObjectEventArgs e) {
  try {
  ...
    d.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
  }

  catch (Exception ex) {
  ...
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    //Handle GridControl.NewItemRowHandle State
    //Or
    //Maintain User Changes
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but mark will give you 100 anyway as you're along here :) Mikhail, why using BeginInvoke, not just calling things directly?